# Pandas: Rolling mean using only the last update based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I would like to perform a rolling mean while the mean excludes duplicates found in another column. Let me provide an example dataframe:

```
Date            Warehose       Value
10-01-1998      London          10
13-01-1998      London          13
15-01-1998      New York        37
12-02-1998      London          21
20-02-1998      New York        39
21-02-1998      New York        17
```

In this example, let's say I like to perform 30-day rolling mean of `Value` but taking into account only the last update of the Warehouse location. The resulting dataframe is expected to be:

```
 Date         Value     Rolling_Mean
02-01-1998      10           10
05-01-1998      13           13
15-01-1998      37           20
12-02-1998      21           29           
20-02-1998      39           30 
21-02-1998      17           19
```

The data I have is relatively big so as efficient as possible is appreciated.

Comment: can you break down the computations for clarity?

Comment: What about the last one (17 -> 19)?

Comment: I had mixed the dates a bit initially. On 21-02-1998 we have London = 21 and New York = 17, so (21+17)/2=19

Comment: All estimations are as follows: On 02-01-1998 we have just London which is 10, then on 05-01-1998 London updates to 13, on 15-01-1998 we get (New York + London) / 2 = (37 + 13 ) / 2 = 20. On 12-02-1998 we update London to 21 so it becomes (37 + 21) / 2 = 29. On 20-02-1998 we update New York to 39, so we get (39 + 21) / 2 = 30 and the last update of New York to 17 makes it (17 + 21) / 2 = 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. As `rolling.apply` works on Series only and you need both "Wharehose" and "Value" to perform the computation, you need to access the complete dataframe using a function (and a "global" variable, which is not super clean IMO):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df2 = df.set_index('Date')

def agg(s):
    return (df2.loc[s.index]
               .drop_duplicates(subset='Warehose', keep='last')
               ['Value'].mean()
           )

df['Rolling_Mean'] = (df.sort_values(by='Date')
                        .rolling('30d', on='Date')
                        ['Value']
                        .apply(agg, raw=False)
                      )
```

output:

```
        Date  Warehose  Value  Rolling_Mean
0 1998-01-10    London     10          10.0
1 1998-01-13    London     13          13.0
2 1998-01-15  New York     37          25.0
3 1998-02-12    London     21          29.0
4 1998-02-20  New York     39          30.0
5 1998-02-21  New York     17          19.0
```